# ¿Es correcta la definición de "freír" del DLE?

Tags: verbos, definiciones, comida, dle

La definición de [freír](https://dle.rae.es/fre%C3%ADr) del DLE es:

> 1. tr. Hacer que un alimento crudo llegue a estar en disposición de poderse comer, teniéndolo el tiempo necesario en aceite o grasa hirviendo.

Si lo entiendo correctamente, esta definición parece indicar que *freír* es una forma de hacer comestible un alimento crudo, que si no no se podría comer.

¿Es correcta mi interpretación? ¿Es acertada la definición del DLE?

Comment: ¿Está cuestionando el DLE?

Comment: @Lambie: ¡Por supuesto!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pienso que parte del problema que tiene sea en su idea de "crudo".

Parte de la definición de [crudo](https://dle.rae.es/crudo) del DLE es :

> 1. adj. Dicho de un alimento: Que no ha sido preparado por medio de la acción del fuego, o que no lo está hasta el punto conveniente.

Entonces, puedo freír un perrito caliente, pero ya es cocido.  Sin embargo es crudo en mi receta de "perrito caliente frito" porque es un ingrediente y no "al punto conveniente" para comer.

Con esta idea son posible comer plátano crudo Y plátano frito, o frutas crudas, porque la definición de crudo es flexible.